# How to manually change the color of certain geom_point?

Tags: r, geom-point

I'm fairly new to R and am wondering how can I manually change certain geom_point's color?

For instance, here's the average velocity of Justin Verlander from 2008 - 2022

```
JVvelo_year%>%
ggplot(aes(factor(year), velo, group = 1))+
geom_line()+
geom_point(size = 5, color = "salmon")+
xlab('Season')+
ylab('Average Velocity')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odUJn.png)

I'd like to change the dots before 2017 to darkblue to align with the Tigers' uniform and keep the dots after 2017 orange.

Thank you

Comment: one option is that you can create a new column with boolean values (1 if year > 2017 else 0) and then in ggplot `aes()` or in `geom_point` use `group_by` argument and set it to the new column which will differentiate the colors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Indicate which row by adding a column:

   ```r
   mtcars$interesting <- "no"
   mtcars$interesting[5] <- "yes"
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point(aes(color = interesting), size = 5)
   ```

   [image: one call to geom_point]

   This has the advantage of being more `ggplot2`-canonical, and will fluidly support legends and other aesthetic-controlling devices.
2. Plot two sets of points, setting `data=` each time.

   ```r
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
     geom_point(size = 5, color = "blue", data = ~subset(., interesting == "no")) + 
     geom_point(size = 5, color = "red", data = ~subset(., interesting == "yes"))
   ```

   [image: individual geom point calls]